# integers can only be combined with integers of same class or scalar doubles error

Tags: matlab

I do not know what this error means or how to fix it. I am trying to perform an image rotation in a separate space of coordinates. When defining the reference space of the matrix to be at zero, I am getting the error that integers can only be comibined with integers of the same class or scalar doubles. the line is

```
WZcentered = WZ - [x0;yo]*ones(1,Ncols);
```

WZ is classified as a 400x299x3 unit 8, in the workspace. It is an image. x0 and y0 are set to 0 when the function is called. How can I fix this issue/what exactly is happening here?

Also, when I do the same thing yet make WZ to be equal to double(WZ) I get the error that 'matrix dimensions must agree.' I am not sure what the double function does however. Here is the whole code.

```
function [out_flag, WZout, x_final, y_final] = adopted_moveWZ(WZ, x0, y0);

%Initial Test of plot
[Nrows,Ncols]=size(WZ);
if Nrows ~= 2
   if Ncols ==2
        WZ=transpose(WZ); %take transpose
        [Nrows,Ncols]=size(WZ); %reset the number of rows and columns
   else
        fprintf('ERROR: Input file should have 2-vectors for the input points.\n');
   end
end

plot(WZ(1,:),WZ(2,:),'.')
title('These are the original points in the image');
pause(2.0)
%WZorig = WZ;

%centering 
WZcentered = WZ - ([x0;y0] * ones(1,Ncols));


FigScale=400;
axis([-FigScale 2*FigScale -FigScale 2*FigScale])
disp('Hit any key to start the animation');
pause;

SceneCenter = zeros(Nrows,Ncols);
WZnew = WZcentered;

for ii=0:20

    %rotate
    R = [cos(pi/ii) -sin(pi/ii) 0; sin(pi/ii) cos(pi/ii) 0; 0 0 1];
    WZnew = R * WZnew; 
    plot(WZnew(1,:),WZnew(2,:),'.')
    %place WZnew at a different place in the scene
    SceneCenter = (ii*[30;40])*ones(1,Ncols);
    plot(SceneCenter(1,:) + WZnew(1,:), SceneCenter(2,:) + WZnew(2,:),'.')
    axis([-FigScale 2*FigScale -FigScale 2*FigScale])
    pause(1.0);


end


%Set final values for output at end of program
x_final = SceneCenter(1,1);
y_final = SceneCenter(2,1);
PPout = PPnew + SceneCenter;
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to `WZ` and `([x0;y0] * ones(1,Ncols))` being of different data types. You might think MATLAB is loosely typed, and hence should do the right thing when you have a floating point type operated with an integer type, but this rule breaks every once in a while. A simpler example to demonstrate this is here:

```
X = uint8(magic(5))
Y = zeros(5)
X - Y
```

This breaks with the same error that you are reporting. One way to fix this is to force cast one of the operands to the other, typically up-casted to make sure the math works. When you do this, both the numbers you are working on are floating point (double precision), and so they are represented in the same byte formatting sequence in memory. This way, the '-' sign is valid, in the same way that you can say 3 apples + 4 apples = 7 apples, but 3 oranges (uint8) + 4 apples (double) = ?. The double(X) makes it clear that you really mean to use double precision arithmetic, and hence fixes the error. This is how it looks now:

```
double(X) - Y
```

After having identified this, the new error is 'matrix dimensions do not match'. This means exactly what it says. WZ is a 400x299x3 matrix, and the right hand side matrix is 2xnCols. Now can you subtract a 2D matrix from a 3D matrix of different sizes meaningfully?

Depending on what your code is really intending to do, you can pad the RHS matrix, or find out other ways to make the sizes equal.

All of this is why MATLAB includes routines to do image rotation, namely http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html . This is part of the Image Processing Toolbox, though.